# Critical points of the function

Tags: multivariable-calculus

How to find the critical points of the function given below.

> $$F(x,y) = x^2+xy+y^2+ \frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}$$

Comment: $$-\frac{1}{x^2}+2x+y=0$$

Answer (score 1):

The critical points of a function from $F:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}$ are those such that the total derivative 
$$ \begin{bmatrix}\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}&\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}\\
\end{bmatrix}_p$$ has rank $0$. Here the subscript $p=(x_0,y_0)$ denotes $p\in \mathbb{R}^2$. That is, it is the set of points so that $\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}=0$. So, take partial derivatives and find the solutions to the system of equations given by $\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}=0$.

Comment: Unrelated: Wow, Berkeley. Don't let the chance of learning some logic go to waste $\ddot \smile$

Comment: I'll be sure not to :).